# Can't run selenium test from Docker container

Tags: python, docker, selenium, selenoid

Please help solve the problem. When running tests using Selenoid directly from the console, the tests work. But when I try to run tests from the container, I encounter the error urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=4444): Max retries exceeded with url: /wd/hub//session (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3 .connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f5c0120db70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  similar_biomarker_api:
    container_name: similar-biomarker-api
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./src:/code
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=0
  selenoid:
    network_mode: bridge
    image: aerokube/selenoid:latest
    volumes:
      - "/home/vitalijj/PycharmProjects/test_dc/config:/etc/selenoid"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "$PWD/video:/opt/selenoid/video"
      - "$PWD/logs:/opt/selenoid/logs"
    environment:
      - OVERRIDE_VIDEO_OUTPUT_DIR=/path/to/config/video
    command: ["-conf", "/etc/selenoid/browsers.json", "-video-output-dir", "/opt/selenoid/video", "-log-output-dir", "/opt/selenoid/logs"]
    ports:
      - "4444:4444" #30444
  selenoid-ui:
    image: aerokube/selenoid-ui
    container_name: "selenoid-ui"
    network_mode: bridge
    links:
      - selenoid
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    command: [ "--selenoid-uri","http://selenoid:4444" ]
```

python-code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

capabilities = {
    "browserName": "chrome",
    "version": "latest",
    "platform": "LINUX"
}

driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/',
    desired_capabilities=capabilities
)



try:
    print('Session ID is: %s' % driver.session_id)
    print('Opening the page...')
    driver.get('https://auth.biodata.group/auth')

    print('Taking screenshot...')
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file(driver.session_id + '.png')

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Screenshot of error when running from docker container:
[Error from docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2EA3.png)

Comment: The containers run in the same network (created by docker-compose) so you might have to use the container name (ie `http://selenoid:4444`)

Comment: I looked at the container address is at 0.0.0.0:4444. I tweaked that value, but I still get the same error.

Comment: `0.0.0.0` means is listening to any IP address (within the container), that's ok. I would create a network in docker-compose and make sure every container uses that network

Comment: Here is an example https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gcatanese/2bee5677f027da725591c6236326dc4f/raw/0173a7eda244e4aad475ea1c2569db708987df79/docker-compose-nginx.yml

Comment: I solved this problem. Registered simply ip the address of the container external. I had it 172.18.0.1